# How to initialize generic array with generic-array crate in rust?

Tags: generics, rust, rust-crates

I use the [generic-array](https://crates.io/crates/generic-array) crate:

```rust
struct Foo<N: ArrayLength<i32>> {
    data: GenericArray<i32, N>
}
```

But it doesn't explain how to initialize value:

```rust
impl<N: ArrayLength<i32>> Foo<N> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            data: // What to puts here?
        }
    }
}
```

Playground [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=db101765fae30bfc1359081d66b95056) to help testers.

Comment: What do you want to initialize it to? Default values? A specific array?

Comment: Something like `[33; N]`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can default-initialize and mutate them afterwards:

```
let mut data = GenericArray::default();
for x in &mut data {
    *x = 33;
}
```

Or you can use the `GenericArray::from_exact_iter` function. The problem is that there does not seem to be an easy way to create an iterator of `n` elements that also implements `ExactSizeIterator`. You can implement one though:

```
struct RepeatN<T>{
    item: T,
    count: usize,
}

impl<T: Clone> Iterator for RepeatN<T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        self.count.checked_sub(1).map(|count| {
            self.count = count;
            self.item.clone()
        })
    }

    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        (self.count, Some(self.count))
    }
}

impl<T: Clone> ExactSizeIterator for RepeatN<T> {
    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.count
    }
}

fn repeat_n<T: Clone>(item: T, count: usize) -> RepeatN<T> {
    RepeatN {
        item,
        count,
    }
}
```

And use it like `GenericArray::from_exact_iter(repeat_n(33, N::to_usize())).unwrap()`.